# Django + Anymail + Mailgun Webhook => no HTTP_AUTHORIZATION in META

Tags: python, django, apache, webhooks, mailgun

I am trying to get a Webhook (on email open) http (not https) post request from Mailgun using Anymail under Django.

After sending an email successfully and open it, the request is sent to my server from Mailgun but then for some reason I keep getting this in my logs:

```
"Missing or invalid basic auth in Anymail Mailgun webhook"
```

I am using Apache server with Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 2.7.12. I tried using Django test server and there it works fine.

In my `setting.py`, I have:

```
ANYMAIL = {
    "MAILGUN_API_KEY": "key-f962ecaf....",
    'WEBHOOK_AUTHORIZATION': 'SJEi3JF...:Qo9Eu1...'
}
EMAIL_BACKEND = "anymail.backends.mailgun.MailgunBackend"
```

And of course Anymail is in my `INSTALLED_APPS`.

The webhook url in Mailgun is:

```
http://SJEi3JF...:Qo9Eu1...@mydomain.com/appname/anymail/mailgun/tracking/
```

I have a feeling that it some how related to Post params blocked by Django.

---

After a deeper check, I have found that no `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` in `request.META` and still I don't know why.

Comment: What version of Anymail were you using? There was [a bug](https://github.com/anymail/django-anymail/commit/af0e36ab6556b372fbf5b92b3dea29fafb1a3866) where webhooks incorrectly enforced CSRF checks, fixed in v0.4.

Comment: I have just encountered the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: In case anyone else comes across this, as I did

WEBHOOK_AUTHORIZATION must now be renamed to WEBHOOK_SECRET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding the following to my apache conf.

```
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```